# find the first term of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

The sum of an infinite geometric series of real numbers is $14,$ and the
sum of the cubes of the terms of this series is $392$.

What is the first term of the series?

**My attempt:** Let the series be $\{ a ,~ ar ,~ar^2 ,\ldots \}$, then the sum is 
$$ s = \frac{a}{1 - r}  = 14 \tag{1}$$
When cubed, the new series is $ a^3,~a^3r^3,~ a^3 r^6, \ldots$
which sums to
$$ \frac{ a^3 }{ 1 -  r^3 }  = 392   \tag{2}$$

Now I got $\frac{a^2}{28}=  1+r+r^2$ after that I'm not able proceed  further.

Any hints/solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $a=14(1-r)$ and $a^3 = (1-r)(1+r+r^2)392$ which implies 
$$a^2=28(1+r+r^2)=196(1+r^2-2r)$$
and so 
$$(2r-1)(r-2)=0\implies r=1/2$$
since $|r|<1.$ And so $a=7.$

Comment: how   $1+ r+r^2  =  1 +r^2-2r$? im  not getting

Comment: They are not equal. $28(1+r+r^2) = 196(1-r)^2$

Comment: okkss .....my  eyes  didn't see 196,,,as  i read so fast ur answer ....and  at  same moment   i was looking  jose  carlos  sir  answer

Answer (score 2):

You started fine. This leads you to the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\dfrac a{1-r}=14\\\dfrac{a^3}{1-r^3}=392.\end{array}\right.$$This system has two solutions: $(a,r)=(-14,2)$ and $(a,r)=\left(7,\frac12\right)$. But only the second one leads to convergent series.